# Fill percentage of total field with MS Access SQL

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to fill, with a SQL query, a field `F` with the percentage over the total of some field `f`, such that each record `F(i)` in field `F` is given by:

```
F(i) = f(i)/SUM_i(f(i))
```

Both fields `f` and `F` and located in a table `MyTable`.

I am however struggling to develop a query which manages to do this. My try was:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (F)
SELECT f/MyField.fSum
FROM MyTable, (SELECT SUM(f) AS fSum FROM MyTable) AS MyField
```

But this code inserts new lines in table `MyTable`. I don't know how I can proceed from here, as my understanding is that the `UPDATE` statement is quite limited and wouldn't be useful for doing this.

Any ideas on how I could manage to do this in the simplest form possible?

I have just called the columns `f` and `F` here for illustration purposes, it is not how they are named in the actual DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET F = f / (SELECT SUM(f) AS fSum FROM MyTable) ;
```

or:

```
UPDATE 
    MyTable AS my,
    (SELECT SUM(f) AS fSum FROM MyTable) AS total
SET my.F = my.f / total.fSum ;
```

As mendosi commented, having two columns with same name in different (upper/lower) case, like `f` and `F` is not recommended in any DBMS and (not sure) probably not even allowed in Access.

---

The above statements however do not work in version 2013. I think they worked in old (1997) version but some change in the Jet engine (3.5? 4.0?) made the queries throw error instead.

Using the `DSUM()` function instead, to do the summation, works:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET F = f / DSUM("f", "MyTable") ;
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49364/discussion-between-ypercube-and-daneel-olivaw).